# Neo4J REST API no intermediary relationship returned

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm working on neo4j with the REST API.

For this request :

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r*2]-(b)  RETURN n,r,b
```

When I display the result into the viewer/browser (localhost:7474).
I haven't the intermediary nodes into the result.
And I haven't the hypotetic relationship between two "node b"

I want to know why ?
And what is the neo4j's viewer method ?

I working on my own viewer is d3js and I need this infomations for display.

Comment: You should also be able to just return the path: `MATCH p=(n:Person)-[r*2]-(b)  RETURN p`

Comment: Ok ! But : Why the neo4j browser show a relationship of 1 level more if have a common relationship between two nodes into the result, and why this relatioship isn't in the result. I don't want another request, I want your restult or understand your result. Thanks Mr Hunger

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a match longer than a single relationship you cannot use a variable specifier. Instead assign the path a variable, `p` in this example:

```
MATCH p=(n:Person)-[*2]-(b)  RETURN n,relationships(p),b
```

Comment: Thanks, and why the neo4j viewer display a different result if isn't the result of the request ?

Comment: :/ I have check more hardly and into the result miss the possible relationship between two "b node".